# set attribute for duplicate array items in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of objects in python. How can I loop through the array and set any objects who have duplicate names as

```
valid=False
```

Here is my test code:

```
class Asset(object):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name
        self.valid = True

items = [
    Asset("doug"),
    Asset("kevin"),
    Asset("kim"),
    Asset("kevin")
]

for x in items:
    print vars(x)
```

So in reality the results of this test should be:

```
> {'name': 'doug', 'valid': True} 
> {'name': 'kevin', 'valid': False}
> {'name': 'kim', 'valid': True} 
> {'name': 'kevin', 'valid': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using hashmaps/dictionary might be suitable.

```
class Asset(object):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name
        self.valid = True

items = [
    Asset("doug"),
    Asset("kevin"),
    Asset("kim"),
    Asset("kevin")
]

frequency_of_names = {}

for item in items:
    name = item.name
    if name in frequency_of_names.keys():
        frequency_of_names[name] = frequency_of_names[name] + 1
    else:
        frequency_of_names[name] = 1

for item in items:
    if frequency_of_names[item.name] > 1:
        item.valid = False

for item in items:
    print item.name, item.valid
```

Output:

```
doug True
kevin False
kim True
kevin False
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension and count method:

```
names = [item.name for item in items]
frequency = {name:names.count(name) for name in names}
# Give us {doug: 1, kevin: 2, kim: 1}

for item in items:
    if frequency[item.name] > 1:
        item.valid = False

for item in items:
    print item.name, item.valid

    # The output is the same from above.
```